# Unmanaged code that doesn't run appropriately on 64bit platform

Tags: c#, 64-bit, unmanaged, 32bit-64bit, intptr

I am using a code which captures a frame from a video which I found in [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/FrameGrabber.aspx)

The code runs great on 32bit, the problem starts when I try to run on 64bit systems.

The exception thrown is "AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory has been corrupted"

I debugged in 32bit and in 64bit platforms and found where the problem is-

```
mediaType = new AMMediaType();

mediaDet.get_StreamMediaType(mediaType);

videoInfo = (VideoInfoHeader)Marshal.PtrToStructure(mediaType.formatPtr, typeof(VideoInfoHeader));
```

After the second line I looked at mediaType contents and it is completely different in 64bit over 32, which causes the next line to throw the exception(mediaType.formatPtr has different value)

I assume the problem is with the type "IntPtr" which size is different on the 2 platforms(4 vs 8 bytes)
the thing is that I don't know how to overcome this problem.

Any kind of help would be good,
thanks in advance,
Liran.

Comment: How are you building your application? What is your target platform?

Comment: "Any CPU", if I build the test project as X86 it works fine, but since that ultimately the code should run under SharePoint platform which is 64bit and I cannot change that- I need to make it work as is without changing the targer platform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found the solution - the problem lies within the DirectShow DLL, FrameGrabber referenced an old version of the dll, I downloaded and replaced the reference with their latest DLL and problem solved.

Thanks for your post, Liran.